# A função handle não está a converter - matlab

Tags: matriz, for, matlab, vector

Olá,

Estou a obter este erro:

> Conversion to function_handle from double is not possible.

Já procurei sobre o erro e tentei alterar o código mas sem sucesso. Será que podem dar uma ajuda?

```
A=[99.23;100.05;91;107.71;104.1];
B=[3441 3441 301720.5;68750 1068750 0;170040 13085020 0;229350 229350 5729350;34194000 0 0];
N=[300000;1000000;13000000;5500000;32800000];
E=[-0.00302;-0.00261;-0.00208];

[c3,r3]=size(A);
[c4,r4]=size(B);

x=sym ('x',[1 c3]);
x=transpose(x);

for i=1:c3
    Valor(i,1)=0;
    for j=1:r4
        Valor(i,1)=@(x)(Valor(i,1)/((1+E(j,1)+x(j,1))^j))+(B(i,j)/((1+E(j,1)+x(j,1))^j));
    end
end
```

O meu objetivo é descobrir o vetor *x* através do *solve* com o vetor *Valorantigo*.

```
Valorantigo(1:c3,1)=A(1:c3,1).* N(1:c3,1) ./100;
eqn=Valor(1:c3,1)==Valorantigo(1:c3,1); 
[solx, param, cond] = solve(eqn, x, 'ReturnConditions', true);
```

Ou seja x, vai ser a solução de:

- Valorantigo(1,1)=3441/(1-0.00302+x1) + 3441/(1-0.00261+x1)^2 + 301720.5/(1-0.00208+x1)^3
- Valorantigo(2,1)=68750/(1-0.00302+x2) + 1068750/(1-0.00261+x2)^2 + 0/(1-0.00208+x2)^3
- Valorantigo(3,1)=170040/(1-0.00302+x3) + 13085020/(1-0.00261+x3)^2 + 0/(1-0.00208+x3)^3
  o mesmo para as restantes linhas...